# Exit Go program on Ctrl+C

Tags: go, signals, channel

I am having some difficulties cancelling my program with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.  I believe my knowledge of channels must be a bit off as I can't wrap my head around why this program won't close with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> when it prompts for the password.

Would anyone be able to say why it won't exit after asking for the "Password" and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/user"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
    "github.com/howeyc/gopass"
)

func main() {
    signalChannel := make(chan os.Signal, 2)
    signal.Notify(signalChannel, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGINT)
    go func() {
        sig := <-signalChannel
        switch sig {
        case os.Interrupt:
            os.Exit(0)
        case syscall.SIGINT:
            os.Exit(0)
        }
    }()

    user, _ := user.Current()
    fmt.Printf("Hi %s, password please: ", user.Username)
    pass := gopass.GetPasswd()
    fmt.Printf("Recieved as: %s\r\n", pass)
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

**Update**

I resolved this by switching to https://github.com/seehuhn/password which listens for signals

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Ctrl-C` is SIGINT. `Ctrl-\` is SIGQUIT (by default). You will want to change the signal your application listens for.

This answer has some further details on the typical (but some implementations may stray) shortcuts for signals in a terminal: https://superuser.com/a/343046/93194

---

Update: [gopass is interfering with your signal handling](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/golang-nuts/0JfeQ-Qu37U). Look at using http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.crypto/ssh/terminal#ReadPassword instead:

```
    state, err := terminal.MakeRaw(0)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer terminal.Restore(0, state)
    term := terminal.NewTerminal(os.Stdout, ">")
    password, err := term.ReadPassword("Enter password: ")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

Comment: updated question to listen for SIGINT rather than SIGQUIT, however still not having any luck.  I believe due to github.com/howeyc/gopass it's not taking in the values appropriately.  Looking in to this more now though, thank you for the information

Comment: I just noticed gopass. Someone had an issue with that on the mailing list a couple of weeks ago—interfering with signal handling. Use the terminal package as part of go.crypto instead: https://github.com/gokyle/readpass/issues/1#issuecomment-47716973